# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: std:terminate(), typeinfo, operator delete[], operator new[], and more

Tags: c++, compilation, linker, clang, std

I am following the Lynda.com C++ Essential Training course, but some of the code isn't compiling. The following example gives an error when compiling:

```cpp
// new-delete.cpp by Bill Weinman <http://bw.org/>
//   updated 2018-10-27
#include <cstdio>
#include <new>
using namespace std;

constexpr size_t count = 1024;

int main() {
    printf("allocate space for %lu long int at *ip with new\n", count);
    
    // allocate array
    long int * ip;
    
    try {
        ip = new long int [count];
    } catch (std::bad_alloc & ba) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot allocate memory (%s)\n", ba.what());
        return 1;
    }
    
    // initialize array
    for( long int i = 0; i < count; ++i ) {
        ip[i] = i;
    }
    
    // print array
    for( long int i = 0; i < count; ++i ) {
        printf("%ld ", ip[i]);
    }
    puts("");
    
    // deallocate array
    delete [] ip;
    puts("space at *ip deleted");
    
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::terminate()", referenced from:
      ___clang_call_terminate in new-delete-a02e2b.o
  "typeinfo for std::bad_alloc", referenced from:
      GCC_except_table0 in new-delete-a02e2b.o
  "operator delete[](void*)", referenced from:
      _main in new-delete-a02e2b.o
  "operator new[](unsigned long)", referenced from:
      _main in new-delete-a02e2b.o
  "___cxa_begin_catch", referenced from:
      _main in new-delete-a02e2b.o
      ___clang_call_terminate in new-delete-a02e2b.o
  "___cxa_end_catch", referenced from:
      _main in new-delete-a02e2b.o
  "___gxx_personality_v0", referenced from:
      _main in new-delete-a02e2b.o
      Dwarf Exception Unwind Info (__eh_frame) in new-delete-a02e2b.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I am compiling the code with `clang -std=c++11`. I am compiling the code through the terminal, not through Xcode. I am running macOS Mojave 10.14.6.

There is a pretty large chance that this I am making a stupid newcomer mistake; if so, please point me in the right direction as I've been looking into this for about an hour and have made zero headway.

Thank you!

Comment: clang is a C compiler. clang++ is the C++ frontend.

Comment: @eerorika Yep, that was it... oops. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Use `clang++`, not `clang`

As pointed out by @eerorika in the comments, `clang` is a C compiler, not a C++ compiler. `clang++` is for C++.